# Generate PHP Interfaces

Tags: php, interface

Is there a tool the generate php interface from existing classes?  It would be nice to have a tool like Netbeans automatic getter/setter creation but for interfaces.

Comment: What you are talking about? Getters/Setters for interfaces don't make any sense, because interfaces cannot have properties. You should clarify your question

Comment: @KingCrunch `nice to have a tool like Netbeans automatic getter/setter creation`  Netbeans offers a "autogenerate getters and setters from the classes properties feature.  He wants something like that for interfaces. "Generate interface from class"

Comment: Ah, I see. Probably edorian already gives an answer, but usually (according "design-by-contract") you should always have the interfaces first and create the classes according their signatures. (Just wanted to mention this)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For programmatic usage there is [**`InterfaceDistiller`**](https://github.com/gooh/InterfaceDistiller) that allows you to derive interfaces from existing classes like this:

```
$distiller = new InterfaceDistiller;
$distiller
    ->methodsWithModifiers(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC)
    ->extendInterfaceFrom('Iterator, SeekableIterator')
    ->excludeImplementedMethods()
    ->excludeInheritedMethods()
    ->excludeMagicMethods()
    ->excludeOldStyleConstructors()
    ->filterMethodsByPattern('(^get)')
    ->saveAs(new SplFileObject('MyInterface.php'))
    ->distill('SomeFoo', 'MyInterface');
```

It also has a CLI interface:

```
Usage: phpdistill [options] <classname> <interfacename>

  --bootstrap                           Path to File containing your bootstrap and autoloader

  --methodsWithModifiers <number>       A ReflectionMethod Visibility BitMask. Defaults to Public.
  --extendInterfaceFrom  <name,...>     Comma-separated list of Interfaces to extend.
  --excludeImplementedMethods           Will exclude all implemented methods.
  --excludeInheritedMethods             Will exclude all inherited methods.
  --excludeMagicMethods                 Will exclude all magic methods.
  --excludeOldStyleConstructors         Will exclude Legacy Constructors.
  --filterMethodsByPattern <pattern>    Only include methods matching PCRE pattern.
  --saveAs                              Filename to save new Interface to. STDOUT if omitted.
```

---

I'm not aware of any IDE that offers such functionality for php.

Answer (score 4):

Currently [PHPStorm 8](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) can do this, maybe prior versions as well.

Steps:

1. Place your cursor on the class name
2. Choose: Refactor -> Extract -> Interface
3. Fill out the options and done.